# Ubuntu version downgrade

Tags: 12.04, downgrade

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.04.I was using 12.04. I am facing some issues with 16.04. Is it possible to downgrade to my old Ubuntu 12.04 without fresh installation.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Suggest : Make a backup of your settings, and your "files to save" ... and reinstall : Ubuntu 12.04.5 →   http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/